# bcrypt does not work on lambda serverless

Tags: node.js, lambda, bcrypt, serverless

I added the bcrypt module, in local it works, but it does not work when I deploy
 I test the function and show this:

```
errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
```

Comment: Did you end up getting this working? I'm running into the same issue now.

Answer (score 6):

You need to deploy using linux environment. If you deploy it from windows machine this error occurred.

Alternatively you can use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) instead of [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

Comment: Very good answer, using bcryptjs solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the python version of this issue (how I ended up here) you need to install the linux version of the package (as well as cffi, cryptography, and PyNaCl which it relies on) and unzip them yourself.

You can do this with:

```
pip download PyNaCl --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --no-deps -d lambda_project/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
pip download cffi --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --no-deps -d lambda_project/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
pip download bcrypt --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --no-deps -d lambda_project/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
pip download cryptography --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --no-deps -d lambda_project/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages

cd lambda_project/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
unzip \*.whl
rm *.whl
```

Comment: how did you get this to work? I am running into the bcrypt error and using python packaging guide from serverless: https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

if i manually build the libraries as you have done, bcrypt does not correctly reference cffi, so I get: Unable to import module 'auth': No module named '_cffi_backend'

Comment: @ToddAnderson It looks like the link you sent uses a docker container approach. My guess without looking into it closely is that your docker container perhaps does not support the manylinux builds and perhaps needs different builds? I _think_ with the approach you linked to though you want to trust the docker container to pull the appropriate platform files? Im really not sure though.

Comment: I got the following error through this approach.  
"module 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl' has no attribute 'hashes'"
I'm on my Local Windows machine trying to deploy to AWS Lambda